# python dictionaries, want to do a list of lists

Tags: list, dictionary

I want to make a connect 4 game, but it involves having lists of lists. Let's say if there is a 'counter' in column 1, then I would have to add 1 to the list name (line1 -> line2). I've used dictionaries but I just end up having tuple errors and unhashable type list errors.
Here's what I've got:

```
col1 = 0
col2 = 0
col3 = 0
col4 = 0
col5 = 0
col6 = 0
col7 = 0

line7 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
line6 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
line5 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
line4 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
line3 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
line2 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
line1 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

alllist = {
line1,
line2,
line3,
line4,
line5,
line6,
line7,
}

a1 = int(input("What column do you want to place your counter on? "))

line1[(a1-1)] = (1)
if line1[0] == (1):
    col1 += 1

b1 = randrange(1,7)
b2 = random.choice(line1,line2,line3,line4,line5,line6,line7)

if b1 == col1:
    alllist[(0)+1] = (2)
```

One error message:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please copy error messages verbatim into your question - it would be great if they stood out as quotes. (What is `lin3`?)

Comment: its meant to be line3, ive fixed that and the errors are:

Comment: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: You are getting the _TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'_ because your `alllist` variable does not have keys for each list value (python is trying to make sense of your dict, but lists are not valid keys).

Answer (score 0):

`Any help would be appreciated!`

If you want maintainable code / code other can be bothered to try and understand, comment it properly (describe why/what-for everything is there (where that isn't glaringly obvious)).

For python&hashability, have a look at the differences between tuples and lists.